# Where statement with conditions is multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I need my code to set values of a column based on two criteria: the value of a different column in the same table and a value of a column in a different table. Is there a way to use the where statement to look at criteria in different tables?

Below is pseudo code that doesn't work but captures what I am trying to do.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET CustomerStatus_2003  = 'New' 
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'New'
AND Table2.Column1 = '2003'
AND Table1.Column2= Table2.Column2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My advice would be to build a SELECT statement that retrieves ONLY the rows that you want to update.  Have that select pull all the data required to make the update.  Then change the SELECT into an UPDATE.  This way you can make sure your JOINs and WHERE clause work the way you think they do before you do the update.

Answer (score 1):

You should always alias your tables and use a JOIN when you are using more than one table in a statement. Here is some code that does what you are looking for

```
UPDATE t
SET myColumn = 'New'
FROM MyTable t
    JOIN OtherTable t2 ON t.Column = t2.Column
WHERE t.SomeCondition
    AND t2.SomeOtherCondition
```